# How can I do IP spoofing in JMeter for LDAP requests?

Tags: jmeter, ldap, ip, spoofing

I am aware that we can do IP spoofing in JMeter for HTTP samplers. But, I am not able to find any option to do the same for LDAP requests. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add some code that shows what you already tried?

Comment: Hi EFrank, I added LDAP extended sampler and then did Bind Operation. I am able to do that. However, I need to run this tests from multiple IP addresses. As of now, Jmeter is taking my local machine IP address to run the test.

Comment: Also, I have not added any script/code for this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Option for IP spoofing with LDAP requests is not available.

Your option would be to code the ldap call yourself in groovy and use JSR223 sampler to call this code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. However, what method I should use for IP spoofing. For example, in case of FTP requests, below can be used:-FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.setPassiveLocalIPAddress("YOUR IP ADDRESS HERE");